# Si no obtengo resultado, cambiar la respuesta por null o cero en SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo el siguiente query que me devuelve como resultado "no existe" por asi decirlo, ya que lo filtro por un numero y dicho numero no existe (es la idea).

[image: resultado]

Ahora, lo que quiero saber y como se podria realizar, es como pasar de no obtener "no existe" a cambiar el valor a null o cero u otra cosa simplemente.

`SQL`:

```
select G323.G303MNTD as SALDO
from GSCF323 G323, GSCF300 G300
where G300.G300CTA = 1104070196 
and G300.G300UUID = G323.G303UUID
```

Estoy utilizando Oracle.

Comment: Revisa el siguiente enlace (https://www.administradortotal.net/basesdedatos/oracle/la-funcion-nvl-oracle/)

Answer (score 1):

No puedo ver tu imagen, estoy desde un server privado... pero puedes hacer esto:

```
 Select NVL(columna, 0) from Tabla
```

como podras ver en caso de que la columna sea null te retornara 0.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que quieres seguir utilizando dicho numero como filtro principalmente lo que puede hacer es quitar el **where** y meterlo en una **CASE**.

```
select 
G323.G303MNTD as SALDO
,CASE WHEN G300.G300CTA = 1104070196 THEN G323.G303MNTD ELSE 0 END SALDO2
from GSCF323 G323, GSCF300 G300 
where G300.G300UUID = G323.G303UUID
```

Teniendo en cuenta que puede manipular la respuesta en case sea diferente de, de igual manera puedes agregar otro when con mas opciones de igualación en dado caso metas el otro where en la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

También sirve [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617), que retorna el primer valor no nulo en una lista de N opciones

```
select COALESCE(G323.G303MNTD, 0) as SALDO
from GSCF323 G323, GSCF300 G300
where G300.G300CTA = 1104070196 
and G300.G300UUID = G323.G303UUID
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar lo siguiente

```
with cte_datos as ( -- Consulta principal
  select G323.G303MNTD as SALDO
    from GSCF323 G323, GSCF300 G300
    where G300.G300CTA = 1104070196 
    and G300.G300UUID = G323.G303UUID
)

select IdModulo from cte_datos  -- Obtiene los datos de la consulta principal
union all
select 0 -- Obtiene los valores por defecto
  where not exists (select * from cte_datos)
```